# How to get a Dataset of values given a DataArray of keys and a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-xarray

The problem is as follows:

**I have:**

- A dictionary `d` whose values are pandas `Series` of coefficients, for instance:

```
d = {
    "key1": pd.Series(index=["coef_1", "coef_2"], data=[0, 1]),
    "key2": pd.Series(index=["coef_1", "coef_2"], data=[1, 2]),
    "key3": pd.Series(index=["coef_1", "coef_2"], data=[-10, 5]),
}
```

The values could also be instances of `dict`, what matters is that the `index` of these `Series` (or keys of the nested `dict`s) are the same.

- A `xarray.DataArray`, `key_xr`, indexed by dimensions `"x"` and `"y"`, where each point's value is a key of `d`, for instance:

```
>>> xr = xarray.DataArray(
    data=[["key1", "key1"], ["key3", "key2"]],
    dims=["x", "y"], 
    coords={
        "lon": (["x", "y"], [[-1, 1], [3, 5]]), 
        "lat": (["x", "y"], [[2, 4], [6, 8]])
    }
)
>>> xr
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 2)>
array([['key1', 'key1'],
       ['key3', 'key2']], dtype='<U4')
Coordinates:
    lon      (x, y) int64 -1 1 3 5
    lat      (x, y) int64 2 4 6 8
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
```

From this, I would like to obtain a `xarray.Dataset` such that:

- It has the same dimensions, coordinates and metadata as `key_xr`
- It has `N` data variables where `N` is the length of the Series/dicts contained in `d`, whose names are the index of the Series/keys of the dicts, and whose values is the corresponding value to that name. In my example, `N` is 2 and the resulting Dataset would have two data variables `"coef_1"` and `"coef_2"` and whose values are selected into `d` according to the contents of `key_xr`

You could summarize this problem as broadcasting `d.__getitem__` over a DataArray, kind of doing `d[key_arr]` and getting a Dataset out of that.

So far, I have found a solution but it involves going back and forth from DataArray to DataFrame then Dataset, which is not very efficient and confusing. Prior to that, I have experimented with `xarray.apply_ufunc` as in:

```
def lookup_func(key):
    return d[key]

result_dataset = xarray.apply_ufunc(lookup_func, key_arr, input_core_dims=[["y", "x"]])
```

but to no avail (I also tried using `output_core_dims=[["y", "x"]]` and/or `vectorize=True`). The problem is, the `key` being passed in `lookup_func` is always the entire array `key_arr.values` rather than one by one, so the lookup operation is not broadcasted.

Is there an elegant way to do this, preferably purely using `xarray` functionality ?